# How to cast UserStore<IdentityUser> to its base class IUserStore<IUser>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity, claims-based-identity

I am trying to use the new asp.net identity provider with my abstraction layer of my models domain, wich have a implementation of Entity Framework, so I would like to use the out of box version of identity with entity framework in my data access layer.

How can I convert an

```
UserStore<IdentityUser>
```

to its base interface

```
IUserStore<IUser>
```

Once UserStore is an implementation of IUserStore, I can get the cast by this:

```
UserStore<IdentityUser> as IUserStore<IdentityUser>
```

But I want to avoid the IdentityUser from EntityFramework references and dependences, to keep my domain layer loosely coupled. So, IdentityUser also are an implementation of IUser I can cast it:

```
IdentityUser as IUser
```

Both cases works, then I would like to do some like this (wich in fact doesnt works directly):

```
UserStore<IdentityUser> as IUserStore<IUser>
```

So, how can I achieve this?

If we look at this [diagram](http://i3.asp.net/media/4459023/1.png) http://i3.asp.net/media/4459023/1.png, we will see what I would like to achieve. Referencing just the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core in my domain layer, but using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework implementation at DataAccess layer by returning the core interfaces for the domain layer.

Comment: IUser is a base class? You would normally only put an I on an interface.

Comment: Whats UserStore and IUserStore? Tried to google but it doesn't appear to be a standard class? Does this inherit List or something?

Comment: Sorry, call it a base interface so if you want. 
Once UserStore is an implementation of IUserStore, I can get the cast by this:

UserStore<IdentityUser> as IUserStore<IdentityUser>;

But I want to avoid the IdentityUser from EntityFramework references and dependences, to keep my domain layer loosely coupled. So, IdentityUser also are an implementation of IUser

Did you get the idea?

Comment: I tried to write something up, but I have far too many if, buts and maybes. In my opinion what you appear to be trying to do is not a good fit for generics.

Comment: You can't do castings like that or stuff like this is possible: say you have the classes `class Dog : IAnamal {}` and  `class Cat : IAnamal {};` and declare the list `List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();`, if I do `IList<IAnamal> anamals = (IList<IAnamal>)dogs` then `anamals.Add(new Cat())` that last command is perfectly legal because `anamals.Add` accepts any `IAnamal`, because of that `dogs[0]` now contains a `Cat`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that sort of thing is legal as long as the interface supports [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee207183.aspx).

Comment: @James Yes, I meant to add that but ran out of edit time, thanks for putting that in to the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast doesn't work because `UserStore<UserIdentity>` is not the same as `UserStore<IUser>` (even if `IdentityUser` implements `IUser`).

If you need `UserStore<IUser>` then I suggest you implement it in that way and cast to the concrete type internally, you can ensure that the concrete type is `IdentityUser` with a constraint e.g.

```
public class UserStore<T> : IUserStore<T> where T: IUser
{
}
```

You would also need to make your interface covariant i.e.

```
public interface IUserStore<out T> where T : IUser
{
}
```

This should allow you to do the following (assuming `IdentityUser` supports `IUser`)

```
IUserStore<IUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
```

Comment: Yes, that is the option I have. Implementing the interfaces for IUserStore<T> where T: IUser and IUser from the core. But I was trying to do that way, to use the out of box implementation from microsoft, but it appears to force to be highly coupled with IdentityUser instead of using just a IUser

Comment: Do you need that type restriction for the concrete class when the interface already has that restriction on `T`? (I honestly don't know, I feel like I should)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yep constraints aren't implied by interfaces, however, `T` will be validated against it.

Comment: http://i3.asp.net/media/4459023/1.png
If we look at this diagram, I will see what I would like to achieve. Referencing just the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core in my domain layer, but using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework implementation at DataAccess layer by returning the core interfaces for the domain layer.

Comment: Se, I am not creating the classes, I just want to return the top level of abstraction, I know the concepts, and this should works: 
IUserStore<IUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
In fact is the first try I had... But it doesnt worked. Still, the Asp.Net internally uses the core abstraction, how it is showed in that diagram.

Comment: @luri `IUserStore<IUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>()` will only work if the interface supports covariance (like I said in my answer). Are you saying you have no control over the `IUserStore<T>` interface? If not, and it's not covariant then you can't do what you are trying to do.