# .NET Core identity multiple User types

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have multiple classes (`A`, `B` and `C`) each extends `IdentityUser<Guid>`. I also have a class called `UserRole` which extends `IdentityRole<Guid>`.

The following is my `DbContext`:

```
public sealed class EntityDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

}
```

I added identities to `IServiceCollection`:

```
        services
            .AddIdentityCore<A>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntityDbContext>()
            .AddRoles<UserRole>()
            .AddUserStore<AUserStore>()
            // .AddRoleStore<TRoleStore>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Same for B, C
```

I also have the following stores:

```
public class AUserStore : UserStore<A, UserRole, EntityDbContext, Guid> { } 
public class BUserStore : UserStore<B, UserRole, EntityDbContext, Guid> { } 
public class CUserStore : UserStore<C, UserRole, EntityDbContext, Guid> { }
```

The following is the error I'm getting:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter
>   'instance 'AUserStore' with ReturnType AUserStore cannot be cast to
>   IUserStore')

I don't know if what I'm doing is possible or not. Thanks for any help or hint.

---

**Update**

I think I got it working:

```
class GenericUserRoleStore : RoleStore<UserRole, EntityDbContext, Guid> { }

        services.AddIdentity<A, UserRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<AUserStore>()
            .AddRoleStore<GenericUserRoleStore>();

        services.AddIdentityCore<B>()
            .AddRoles<UserRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<BUserStore>()
            .AddRoleStore<GenericUserRoleStore>();

        services.AddIdentityCore<C>()
            .AddRoles<UserRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<CUserStore>()
            .AddRoleStore<GenericUserRoleStore>();
```

Comment: This question ask about multiple users too, in case it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073374/how-to-create-two-type-of-users-with-identity-and-net-core-2
This question is asking about casting, which is similar to your error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929050/how-to-cast-userstoreidentityuser-to-its-base-class-iuserstoreiuser

Answer (score 5):

Both comments on `AddIdentity` and `AddIdentityCore` have this:

> Adds and configures the identity system for the specified User and Role types.

and,

1. Compare source code for [AddIdentity<>](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38-L101) and [AddIdentityCore<>](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33-L55),
2. Review the default code from project template:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
       services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
       ....
   }
   ```

I would say: IdentityFramework got confused when you register multiple identity types to it, but we do need it.

I believe what you are looking for are these posts:

1. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 1 – Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)
2. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)
3. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 3 – Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

you have 3 above `normal` options to `map` your any `UserType` data to database. and the 1st options give you best performance, but give you very messive `datatable` when your usertypes are pretty complex. you would choose either of them for your real project as a balance.

Here is sample code with 1st approach:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base()
    {
        UserRoles = new HashSet<ApplicationUserRole>();
    }

    public int YearsOfExperience { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectManager : ApplicationUser
{
    public bool Talktive { get; set; }
}

public class Developer : ApplicationUser
{
    public bool IsCSharper { get; set; }
}

public class Tester : Developer
{
    public bool WhiteBox { get; set; }
}

public class Documenter : Tester
{
    public List<string> Languages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //get following users directly by following properties
    public DbSet<ProjectManager>  ProjectManagers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Developer>  Developers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tester>  Testers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Documenter>  Documenters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //prevent creating tables for following usertypes
        builder.Ignore<ProjectManager>();
        builder.Ignore<Developer>();
        builder.Ignore<Tester>();
        builder.Ignore<Documenter>();


        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(u => u.UserRoles).WithOne(x => x.User).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            //tell database to use this column as Discriminator
            entity.HasDiscriminator<string>("UserType");
        });

        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.RoleId });
            entity.HasOne(x => x.Role).WithMany(x => x.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            entity.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
    }
}
```

when you need your users:

```
var allUsers = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
var allProjectManagers = await _dbContext.ProjectManagers.ToListAsync();
var allDevelopers = await _dbContext.Developers.ToListAsync();
var allTesters = await _dbContext.Testers.ToListAsync();
```

The next thing you want to configure is UserManager, instead of IUserStore.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager<TUser, TRole>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser
    where TRole : ApplicationRole

{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<TUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<TRole> _roleManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationDbContext context,
        UserManager<TUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<TRole> roleManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
    //customize your own base logics here.

}

public class DeveloperUserManager : ApplicationUserManager<Developer, ApplicationRole>
{

}

public class DocumenterUserManager : ApplicationUserManager<Documenter, ApplicationRole>
{

}
```

Enjoy it.