# How Can I store two different user in database using asp.net core Identiy?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my project, I want to store two different user in database. For example I have student table and teacher table both of them hava different property so I want to store them seperate table but asp.net core identity dont allow me because when student class inherit IdentityDbContext after this I did same thing for teacher class I have an error because IdentityDbContext only allow one entity class. It only allow one table as Student. How can I create two table in asp.net core identity entity framework.

Comment: Do you need to store different data for student and teacher? If the data is similar it could be better to implement student and teacher as roles.

Comment: @michaela112358 yes I need that but datas different for example teacher has different property in own entitiy class.

Comment: use my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848481/net-core-identity-multiple-user-types/58866513#58866513

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a base class, called something like user or person that inherits from IdentityDbContext. Then have teacher and student inheriting from your base class.

The following tutorial explains how to Implement inheritance in ASP.NET MVC with EF Core.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance