# ASP.NET CORE Identity, inject an abstract class for SignInManager generic type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want to have different types of IdentityUser in my project.

So I created an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractUser : IdentityUser
{}
```

But whenever I want to inject a SignInManager with this generic type, I get the following error:

```
No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[EZShop.Helpers.AbstractUser]' has been registered.
```

I have created an ***AppUser*** class, which inherits from ***AbstractUser***.

My **Startup.cs** class looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SiteDbContext>();
```

And the **DbContext** class looks like this:

```
public class SiteDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AbstractUser>
{
    public SiteDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

So, it seems like its not possible to have such an injection:

```
@inject SignInManager<AbstractUser> signInManager
```

Is there any workaround for it? or is there anything I did not understand well?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating multiple 'types' of users, and if so, what for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Right now I need an extension of IdentityUser having "images" property. But, what if later I want other users with other properties? Is this possible to have such an abstraction as I stated?

Comment: It's possible, look at this Stack post: [Net core identity multiple user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848481/net-core-identity-multiple-user-types#58866513). It's just not what I'd recommend. Rather, I'd use a simpler solution that has only 1 type of IdentityUser, the AppUser. Then create tables for the other types AppUserExtension / AppUserSomething (ofc choose better class names!) , and put a data access layer in between. You can map them one-way, so AppUser does not have to have a reference to AppUserExtension, but the userExtension has a reference to the AppUser.

Comment: Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you so much again, do you mean using table per hierarchy? The post you sent me is also good. What made me confused is, can I use an abstract class inside the generic type like this: <AbstracClass>? And then in the startup, when I register identity with Identity<ConcreteClass>, it understands. Because in the error it seems that .NET does not understand to create an instance of my concrete user for the abstract one by specifying it inside the AddIdentity<ConcreteUser> method. I hope my sentences are understandable.

Comment: I mean, I want to use something abstract like, "IUserManager<IUser>" and then in the Dependency Container register something like "UserManager<ConcreteUser>. Is it feasible for "UserManager<IdentityUser>"?

Comment: But what for? The `IUserManager<TUser>` is already an abstraction. You can create a `ICustomUserManager<IUser>` and in the derived class you can check the concrete type of IUser, which you use to target the correct <IUserManager<TUser>. I just don't see the point in the requirement you're putting on the abstract user class. Sorry I can't help you any more.